# Why order of centralizer of $x$ is greater than $1$ in a particular group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was reading a proof of one of the theorem of group theory where the following was written:

> $G$  is a group with $|G|=p^n$, $n$ is any natural number.
> $x_i$ is an element of $G$.
> Since, $x_i$ does not belong to the center of the group and $C(x_i)$ is a subgroup of the group (where $C(x_i)=\{g \in G\mid x_ig=gx_i\}$ , so $|C(x_i)|=p^{k_i}$, where $0<k_i<n$

I was wondering why $k_i>0$. Is it because identity always belongs to $C(x_i)$ and since $x_i$ is not in the center so $x_i$ not equal to identity and $x_i$ also belong to G ?

Comment: Did you really mean to use the [tag:graph-theory] tag?

Comment: I am really sorry. I did it absent mindedly. Apologies!

Answer (score 2):

Assume $G$ is a non-trivial group, then for every non-trivial element $x$, both $x$ and $e$ commute with $x$, so $C(x) \geq 2$.

Comment: I have usually seen non-identity instead of non-trivial, but still +1.

Answer (score 0):

If a group has order $p^n$ then it doesn't have a trivial center. Since the centralizer of $x$ contains the center we conlcude the centralizer of $x$ cannot be trivial.

Although I think the centralizer of $x$ always has size at least $2$ if $x$ is an element of a group with more than $1$ element. If $x$ is $e$ then it is clear, and otherwise we have that $e$ and $x$ are in the centralizer.